# ¿Cómo redireccionar a https sin www usando .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Estuve buscando en la web un ejemplo para redireccionar todo sin `www` encontré lo siguiente:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Follow symbolic links.
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# Prevent directory listings
Options All -Indexes
```

> Esto no se exactamente que hace `Options All -Indexes` `Options +FollowSymLinks` e intentando con algunos ejemplos sin éxito.

Pero no funciona puedo ingresar sin problemas y, no me redirecciona a `https`

Lo que deseo lograr, es que si ingresa a mi sitio web de esta manera:

```
www.example.com/
example.com/
o
http://www.example.com/
http://example.com/
```

Redireccionar siempre a:

```
https://example.com/
```

Sin uso de `www`

Comment: ¿No redirecciona en ningún caso, o en qué casos específicos no realiza la redirección? Ejemplo: si entras a http://www.example.com y si entras a http://example.com, ¿hace la redirección en algún caso?

Comment: @jachguate Hola, si ingreso así `https://www.example.com/` lo deja tal cual y, si ingreso así `http://www.example.com/` lo permite ya sin la validación del certificado de seguridad no le agrega el protocolo `https` ahora si ingreso así `https://example.com/` lo permite también sin intento esto `http://example.com/` me lo redirecciona a: `https://example.com/` *Ahora* pero todo caso yo solo deseo tener lo siguiente `https://example.com/` ya sea en cualquiera de los casos siempre redireccionar a `https://example.com/` sin el uso de `www` puedes ayudarme por favor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intentá de la siguiente manera.

**SIN www (todas las visitas van a "https://domain.com"):**

```
#comienza
RewriteEngine On
# sin www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
# https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente :) gracias.

Comment: me alegra mucho! cualquier duda mandame tu mensaje, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que tu conjunto de reglas redirige solamente cuando no está presente la cadena `www.` al inicio de la URL. Esto lo haces con esta regla:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
```

Puedes resolverlo eliminando esa línea del archivo de configuración de apache, reiniciando el servicio y debiera funcionar como esperas.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Follow symbolic links.
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# Prevent directory listings
Options All -Indexes
```

Comment: Ahora cunado intento `http://www.example.com` me redirecciona a `https://www.example.com` pero me permite el uso de `www` yo solo deseo mostrar mi sitio así `https://example.com` sin `www` :(

Comment: Tienes toda la razón. Pregunta, tienes multiples dominios en este host o esta configuración aplica solo para un dominio?

Comment: Solo la deseaba para la especificaciones comentadas exactamente para un dominio.